# Let $f(x)= \sin^{-1}(2e^x)$. What is $f '(\ln(3/10)$?

Tags: calculus

So I tried switching $y= \sin^{-1}(2e^x)$ with $x= \sin(2e^y)$ and then finding the derivative. The answer does not seem to match up. Thanks for the help

Comment: It should be $x=\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin y\right)$. Your inverse is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It should be $x=\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin y\right)$.

$$\sin y = 2e^x\\
\frac{1}{2}\sin y = e^x\\
\log\left(\frac{1}{2}\sin y\right) = x$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $\sin y=2e^x$, $y'\cos y=2e^x$ and you have $y'=\frac{2e^x}{\cos \sin^{-1}(2e^x)}$.

Comment: $\cos \sin^{-1} u$ has a closed form.

Comment: How would you get the answer 3/4 by plugging in ln(3/10) in y'?

Comment: Note that $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$, and $2e^{\ln(3/10)}=3/5$, so $\cos(\sin^{-1}(3/5)=4/5$. Therefore $y'=\frac{3}{5}/\frac{4}{5}=3/4$.